# How can protectionist policies keep wages low?

Tags: germany, protectionism, services

A German economist who also worked at the ECB [notes](http://www.euronews.com/2017/03/07/view-how-to-understand-germany-s-trade-surplus) that:

> Germany’s bilateral trade surplus with the US has barely changed, despite substantial swings in the euro-dollar exchange rate – which was as high as €1:\$1.60 in 2011, and as low as €1:\$1.04 more recently. Germany owes its export success not to currency manipulation, but to its strong market position and the pricing power of its highly specialized manufacturing champions. [...]
>
> The euro is not too weak, and German exports are not too high. Rather, the problem is that Germany’s imports are too low, owing to its huge investment gap. [...] The gap is the result of policy failures – namely protectionist policies in the non-tradable services sector. The International Monetary Fund, the European Commission, and the OECD have long tried to convince Germany to deregulate services, curtail vested interests, and improve competition. But, as it stands, wages, productivity, and investment remain high in the German export sector, and low in the non-tradable services sector.

How can protectionist policies keep wages *low*, e.g. in services? Usually protectionist policies (e.g. tariffs on imports) tend to increase wages by protecting the local workforce from outside competition. A typical form of barrier to entry in services, namely professional licenses also increase wages (by decreasing labor supply) as far as I know. So how can protectionist policies achieve the opposite effect of lowering wages, particularly in services sector?

Comment: A nudge rather than an answer: the phrase "protectionist policies in the non-tradable services sector" (i.e. services that *can't* be traded internationally) suggests that the author is using the term "protectionist" in its less technical sense, "stuff I don't like": which he explains as too much regulation of services, vested interests and lack of competition.  Not immediately clear how these would push up wages, but a sprawling enough range that there are plenty of mechanisms to choose from.